# FilterRules works in DateListPlot but not in Plot

Tags: plotting, argument-patterns, attributes

I just experience the following problem (this is a MWE just to illustrate). First `DateListPlot`

```
v = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, 5];
t = Range[5]
ts = TimeSeries[v, {t}]
```

and

```
ClearAll[showTS];
showTS[ts_, options_: OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{},
  DateListPlot[ts, FilterRules[options, Options[DateListPlot]]]
  ]
```

then

```
showTS[ts, {ImageSize -> Small}]
```

works fine. But

```
ClearAll[showSomething];
showSomething[f_, options_: OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{},
  Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 10}, FilterRules[options, Options[Plot]]]
  ]
```

and

```
showSomething[x^2, {ImageSize -> Medium}]
```

gives an error message:

```
"Plot: Options expected (instead of 
FilterRules[{ImageSize->Medium},Options[Plot]]) beyond position 2...."
```

I do not understand why? It is nearly the same code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's compare the attributes of `Plot` and `DateListPlot`:

```
Attributes[Plot]
Attributes[DateListPlot]
```

returns

```
{HoldAll, Protected, ReadProtected}
{Protected, ReadProtected}
```

Unlike `DateListPlot`, `Plot` **holds** its arguments from evaluation. Here is a solution that solves your problem:

```
ClearAll[showSomething];
showSomething[f_, options_: OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{}, 
  Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 10}, 
   Evaluate@FilterRules[options, Options[Plot]]]]
```

(note I've added `Evaluate`). And here is a proper way to call your code - you need an pure function, not a formula:

```
showSomething[#^2 &, {ImageSize -> Medium}]
```

[image]

Comment: If you insist on typing formula as a parameter to `showSomething`, as opposed to a pure function, you would need to do more trickery with evaluation.

Comment: The main point is to force an evaluation with `Evaluate[]` of something that needs to be evaluated (e.g. `FilterRules[]`) inside a function with a `HoldAll` attribute. Thus: `showSomething[f_, range_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := Plot[f, range, Evaluate @ FilterRules[{opts}, Options[Plot]]]` (note the arguments inside `FilterRules[]`!) and then you can do `{showSomething[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 π}, Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> Red], 
 showSomething[Sin[x], x ∈ Interval[{0, 2 π}], Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> Red]}`.

Comment: @VictorK.: I should have seen this from the error message (but sometimes one does not see the obvious) - thank you for the fast answer.